# MySQL table .new supposedly does not exist, when referencing in trigger

Tags: mysql, triggers

I have the following three (InnoDB-) tables in a `MySQL` database:

```
Entity (DLID)
Category (CatID, CatName)
hasCategory (DLID, CatID)
```

Now, upon insertion into the table `hasCategory` I would like to make sure, that each `Entity` is associated with at least one `Category`. Thus, I wrote the following trigger:

```
delimiter |

create trigger Max before insert on hasCategory for each row begin
    if  (exists (select distinct DLID from Entity where not exists (select distinct new.DLID from new))) then
        signal sqlstate '45000'
            set message_text = 'Min of 1 category per entity required';
    end if;
end|

delimiter ;
```

Now, when I execute the following query: `insert into hasCategory values (1, 1);` I get the error `error code 1146: table mydb.new does not exist`. I have created some other triggers similar to this one, also referring to the new-table, where it worked perfectly well. Yet, I don't get it, what causes the error in this particular trigger.

Is it possible that the `select` statement causes some trouble? I've read that only `select into` statements are valid in procedures, but I don't know if this has got anything to do with this.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select distinct new.DLID from new
```

there is no table `new` in your DB just as the error states. You can use `NEW` for the record that will be inserted in your trigger but you cannot use it as a table name and select from it.

try

```
if (select 1 from Entity where DLID = new.DLID) = 1 then
```

Comment: Thanks! Do you happen to know an alternative how I could implement this trigger?